# Import error in Visual Studio Code for bs4

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, beautifulsoup, pip

I am having a huge problem with my Visual Studio Code and importing, really any modules I have installed.

For example, recently I have installed BeautifulSoup4, however Visual Studio Code doesn't seem to want to import it, yet when I import it through something like idle or python in cmd or powershell it works completely fine.

I am installing this by using pip; I've tried pip install bs4, pip install BeautifulSoup4, pip install beautifulsoup4. Everytime it says it is installed and satisfied however in Visual There Seems to be a persisting problem.

I have tried uninstalling bs4 and reinstalling it however this doesn't seem to work.

This is what I am writing:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

This is the output I get in Visual Studio Code:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

However when I run this through a python terminal it works completely fine and imports as it should.

Comment: Did you select the right interpreter at VS Code?

Comment: I'm not sure, how would I check this?

Comment: On the bottom at the status bar you can see the selected interpreter on the left side. With F1 and type the command "Python: Select Interpreter" you can select the right interpreter you want. Or just click on the interpreter on the status bar to change it. Make sure that you installed your package on the selected Python version.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this has solved the problem. I had to change the interpreter  to the 64bit version.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and resolved it using the Anaconda package and Jupyter Notebook. Downloaded the package, installed it, and had the same issues while working with VS Code. Used Anaconda and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I use both visual studio code and anaconda so just need to click to Python intepreter at the bottom left to change python environment to ananconda vent which already installed lot of modules and tensorflow or pytorch backend as well